# How can I boost the weighting of a particular relationship in Neo4j/Cypher?

Tags: boost, neo4j, cypher, relationship, dijkstra

I'm finding similar movies with the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)-[r*1..2]-(m2:Movie)
WHERE m.movieID = '1'
UNWIND r AS rels
WITH count(rels) as foo, m2, m
ORDER BY foo desc
RETURN DISTINCT m2.title
LIMIT 25
```

Basically it finds movies with common relationships, and returns movies ordered by those with the most common relationships to `m`. However, some relationships are more important than others. For example, I'd like to boost the `[:DIRECTED]` relationship so that movies directed by the same director are returned before others. How can I do this? Something like Dijkstra's algorithm with the `:DIRECTED` relationship having a low cost?

Answer (score 1):

It is easier than that, you can just use an expression with `CASE` to apply weights.

```
MATCH (m:Movie)-[r*1..2]-(m2:Movie)
WHERE m.movieID = '1'
UNWIND r AS rels
WITH rels,case type(rels) when "DIRECTED" then 1.2 else 1.0 end as weight
WITH sum(weight) as foo, m2, m
ORDER BY foo desc
RETURN DISTINCT m2.title
LIMIT 25
```